# How can I use VBA to remove all embedded videos in a powerpoint file?

Tags: vba, powerpoint

I would like to automate the removal of all embedded videos in powerpoint presentations. I have looked through the Office VBA docs at Microsoft documentation but I do not see any reference to videos. Any help is appreciated.

Answer (score 0):

```
Sub RemoveVideos()

Dim oSl As Slide
Dim oSh As Shape
Dim x As Long

For Each oSl In ActivePresentation.Slides
    For x = oSl.Shapes.Count To 1 Step -1
        With oSl.Shapes(x)
            If .Type = msoMedia Then
                If .MediaType = ppMediaTypeMovie Then
                    .Delete
                End If
            End If
        End With
    Next     ' x
Next    ' Slide

End Sub
```